# Typo3 Fluidtemplate multilanguage how to?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid

I use this Typoscript code:

```
lib.search = FLUIDTEMPLATE
lib.search.file = {$partialsTemplatesPath}search.html
```

Whats the best way to use multilanguage inside this Fluidtemplate?
Using `lib.search.variables` and `GP:L` conditions cant be the best way, right?

**UPDATE:**
Template:

```
<f:translate key="LLL:{locallangPath}locallang.xlf:search" />
```

XLF File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<xliff version="1.0">
    <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="messages" date="2013-10-21T12:50:51Z" product-name="content">
        <header/>
        <body>

            <trans-unit id="search">
                <source>Search</source>
            </trans-unit>

        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

Translated XLF (de.locallang.xlf):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<xliff version="1.0">
    <file source-language="de" datatype="plaintext" original="messages" date="2013-10-21T12:50:51Z" product-name="content">
        <header/>
        <body>

            <trans-unit id="search">
                <target>Suche</target>
            </trans-unit>

        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

This is the right way I guess. But the output is only "Search" and not "Suche". Did I miss something?

Comment: Did you end up solving this? Having a similar problem.

Comment: @newenglander: i used the method above. it seems it was a strange bug. a mix of cache problems and a bad plugin setup.

Answer (score 1):

For the translated one you have to specify source AND target language:

take a look at:
http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/6.2/Internationalization/Introduction/Index.html

hope that works for you...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the translate viewhelper inside of your fluidtemplate.

See: https://fedext.net/viewhelpers/fluid/TranslateViewHelper.html

Comment: Ok, but where is the "global" locallang.xlf? As you can see, this is no extension... so where am i getting the keys from?

Comment: You can store your locallang.xlf wherever you want to. For Example fileadmin/l10n/locallang.xlf. And the translateviewhelper could look like: <f:translate key="LLL:fileadmin/l10n/locallang.xlf:key" />
edit: some typo

Comment: ok i see... how to use 2 different languages in only one .xlf file? right now only the "default" language appears

Comment: If you use xlf files, you have to seperate them for each language. See http://docs.typo3.org/TYPO3/CoreApiReference/Internationalization/Introduction/Index.html edit: But you have to call only the main xlf file in the translate viewhelper